# Service worker, how it work?

Tags: service-worker

I have a form. And I want to make the page resilient to network lashes. 
Outages.
So if you press submit but you have no network, it should be cached somewhere and sent later.
How can I do that? Can Service Work help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deffer failed requests using service workers, yes.

I recommend to use [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) and more specificly the [BackgroundSync Plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync) to deffer failed requests when the network is back.

To do this, you may be familiar with the new [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)